# Issue on upgrading 'react-native-draggable-flatlist' from 1.1.9 to 2.3.3

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am unable to upgrade react-native-draggable-flatlist, it is asking me to install react-native-reanimated and upgrade react-native-gesture-handler then also I am geting lots of issues.

I am using "react-native": "0.59.10"